# Select rows in SQL that do not exist, given the existence of their references

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose that I have a table `rating` which is unique to the pair `user` and `client`.
The schema of `rating` would hold `user_id` and `client_id` along with some other information (like `score` and `comment`).

At some point I might have the following situation where a `*` represents the existence of a `rating` for the corresponding `user_id` and `client_id`.

```
        user1 user2 user3 user4
client1   *     *     *     *
client2   *     *     *     *
client3   *           *      
client4   *           *     *
```

In pure SQL, how can one select the rows with elements of `user_id` and `client_id` where a `*` does *not* exist?

In my example, the correct result should be

```
user_id  client_id
-------- ---------
2        3
2        4
4        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this would be by constructing a query, involving `LEFT JOIN`, which included every combination whether valid or not, and then filtering to just those which have no data from the `rating` part of the `JOIN`.

In this case, we want a row for every combination of `user` and `client`, so that part requires a `CROSS JOIN`, with the `ratings` table `LEFT JOIN`ed onto that.

Here's the query with all possible combinations, and ratings where available ([Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef8af/1)):

```
SELECT
  U.user_name,
  C.client_name,
  R.rating
FROM
  users as U
CROSS JOIN
  clients as C
LEFT JOIN
  ratings as R
  On R.user_id = U.user_id
  And R.client_id = C.client_id
ORDER BY
  U.user_name,
  C.client_name;
```

From that output, it's hopefully clear that to find combinations where no rating exists, we can just add `WHERE R.rating IS NULL` ([Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef8af/2)):

```
SELECT
  U.user_name,
  C.client_name,
  R.rating
FROM
  users as U
CROSS JOIN
  clients as C
LEFT JOIN
  ratings as R
  On R.user_id = U.user_id
  And R.client_id = C.client_id
WHERE
  R.rating IS NULL
ORDER BY
  U.user_name,
  C.client_name;
```

(Note that there is no specific syntax in SQL to say "where the Left Join didn't match anything in the Right table", you just have to pick a non-nullable column, like I have with `rating` in this example.)

Comment: There is `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` for the cases `where the Left Join didn't match anything in the Right table`

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I don't know of any way to use those with a `LEFT JOIN`, only with a sub-query as shown in your answer. In this case, it comes to the same thing, but sometimes you want to perform complex logic (an `OR`, or a `CASE`, for instance) which uses data from the `LEFT JOIN`ed table if available, but knows for sure if there is not. It just feels ugly sometimes having to test a primary key against `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
CROSS JOIN clients
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM rating
                  WHERE rating.user_id = users.user_id
                    AND rating.client_id = clients.client_id)
```